# I can only make my shell script run by interrupting it

Tags: linux, fedora

Here is the code:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo hello world!
sxhkd -c $HOME/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc
echo done sxhkd
setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape
echo done setxkbmap
xset r rate 250 60
echo done xset
```

I want this to run on startup so I put it in crontab with @reboot /home/name/startup.sh, it didn't work, so I tried running the script myself and it echos hello world!, then nothing happens and there is no new prompt, but when I press ctrl+c to stop the program, the rest of it runs fine. How do I fix this? I'm on fedora.

Answer (score 1):

Put a '&' at the end of the sxhkd line to run it in the background, or it'll be stuck on that line until you quit sxhkd, which you presumably don't want to do.

```
sxhkd -c $HOME/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc &
```

But I'm not really sure you want to run this from a cronjob. Don't you want to run this as your user? Maybe start it from your `.xinitrc`, or other start up script that your window manager or desktop environment uses?

Comment: I can't get the script to run from .xinitrc or .xsession, but running either manually does run the script successfully. I think .xsession is doing something because earlier I copied /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc into it and dwm didn't load on startup (it's back to normal now).

Comment: How are you starting dwm? With `startx` or with a display manager? Do you have the autostart patch?

Comment: I think it's a display manager? On the login screen there is a cog in the bottom right, I just select dwm from there. I don't have the autostart patch